# Sql server 2008 installation failure

Tags: sql-server

When i install the Sql Server 2008 in my PC, i got the error prompt.

The error message is

**object reference not set to an instance of an object**

My pc is running on Windows Xp Professional SP2.

Answer (score 1):

Strange as it may sound, I got this error whenever I focused a different window while the setup for SQL Server was initializing. This, however, was on Windows 7. When I made sure not to focus any other window during setup initialization, installation ran fine.